# Resetting Netbeans 8.x GIT versioning (folder ?)

Tags: git, netbeans, initialization, repository

I am using Netbeans 8.1 IDE  (Windows) and I am a complete noob at versioning on the first step of the learning curve, and I have accidentally deleted the GIT folder (was apparently empty) created by Netbeans 8.1 upon Versioning Git initialisation.

Now I see all my files in Netbeans tree-view green-coloured as if versioning is active, however the Git folder in the filesystem is still empty. I suspect Netbeans being fooled somehow so I have closed Netbeans and deleted the cache folder however once restarted, GIT seems to be there, enabled and working.

To ensure GIT is working as expected I'd like to completely reset versioning to it's initial state so I can create again the repo folder and verify it is working as expected but I don't know how to achieve this.

EDIT: 
I see the .git folder as it was hidden in the filesystem, so I was wrong I did not delete the folder! However to ensure everything is working as expected how can I reinitialise this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However to ensure everything is working as expected how can I reinitialise this?

Deleting (or at least moving) that .git folder would be a good first step.
Then use Netbeans to [re-initialize your repo](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html#initialize).

Comment: Thanks mate, I will try this

Comment: I have successfully reinitialised the repo, however no files in the project are added to it and no contextual menu allows to add files in the repo....

Comment: Try at lest a git init . in your project folder

Comment: Yes, to initialize a new git repository, and see if netbeans detects it.